# Unable to resize logical_volume with Ansible

Tags: ansible, filesystems

I use Ansible in order to resize an existing logical volume as follows: :

```yaml
- name: Redimensionnement du volume logique
  lvol:
    lv: "{{ LV }}"
    vg: "{{ VG }}"
    size: "{{ size }}"
    force: yes
    resizefs: yes
```

However, I get the following error :

```jenkins
fatal: [server]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "err": "fsadm: Cannot get FSTYPE of \"/dev/mapper/{{ VG }}-{{ LV }}".\n  Filesystem check failed.\n", "msg": "Unable to resize {{ LV }} to {{ size }}", "rc": 5}
```

Why cannot I get FSTYPE ?

How may I get it ?

Comment: It looks like your vars (LV, VG, size) were not expanded. Can you show your complete playbook with var definition and the command you used to launch it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the solution :

I removed the `resizefs` parameter. Indeed, its default value is `no`, that's means the underlying filesystem is not resized together with the logical volume.

In my case the resize of the logical volume is sufficient :

```yaml
- name: Redimensionnement du volume logique
  lvol:
    lv: "{{ LV }}"
    vg: "{{ VG }}"
    size: "{{ size }}"
    force: yes
```

Answer (score 0):

The vars definition :

```yaml
LV: "lv_folder"
VG: "data_vg"
```

The command I used :

```shell
ansible-playbook -i hosts.ini playbook.yml -e size=20G -v
```